# How can I insert a view inside another view in blade engine in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

How can I insert a view blade inside another view in blade engine in laravel

I am working in a project that's contains :
   home view ......"**home.blade.php**"

I want to add another page "**home2.blade.php**"

So finally I got 1 page which is "**home.blade.php**" but it contains "**home2.blade.php**"

this is the home2.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<!-- All Posts -->
@if(count($posts) > 0)

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        All Posts
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped task-table">

            <!-- Table Headings -->
            <thead>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Content</th>
            </thead>

            <!-- Table Body -->
            <tbody>
            @foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <td class="table-text">
                        <div>{{$post->title}}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-text">
                        <div>{{$post->content}}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

  @endif

  @endsection
```

and this is "**home.blade.php**"

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

 <body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#navigation">


  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <div id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
  data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please share the code of 'layouts.app' view.

Comment: You can look up the `@include`

Answer (score 0):

use `include()` in home.blade.php

Ex: if your home2 is located in `resources/views/`

```
@include('home2')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `@include('filename')` directive. [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#including-sub-views)

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#navigation">

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>

        @include('home2') <-- your home2.blade.php file will be added here
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I tried and I can confirm that this works, at least for Laravel 5+ (I have L5.2). This is how I suggest you to use your blade templates.

Lets start saying that to yield a section into another section you have to define your included section before container section definition. So, with that clear, I solved this situation like this:

I got a main blade (main.blade.php) template which has something like:

```
<section class="content">
  <!-- Your Page Content Here -->
  @yield('main-content')
</section><!-- /.content -->
```

I got a second blade (common.blade.php) template which has that common stuff you may want to show across many pages and where main-content section is defined. This one looks like:

```
@section('main-content')
   <div class="container">
      @yield('extra-content')
   </div>
@endsection
```

Finally I got a 3rd template (test.blade.php) which extend the main template and include the common stuff I want to show, but be careful because the order matters. This one looks like:

```
@extends('main')
@section('extra-content')
   <div>
      <span> This is a test! </span>
   </div>
@endsection
@include('common')
```

In your controller or your route (wherever you return your view), you should return the 3rd template.

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: i want to make @section get data from table in mysql , and use this section as i like anywhere any blade page

Comment: Then just Create a page with your respective Table record and include this page inside your blade . That's it bro